# Combining js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, compass-sass, gulp

I recently started to use Gulp.js along with Sass and Compass. I originally started my project outside this environment using an antiquated index.html with css and js folder. All my JS files were being loaded separately. (e.i. jQuery, iLightbox, etc.)

Now that my JS files are being combined to one file, I and getting several errors. What should I be looking out for? Keep in mind, I'm not the greatest javascript/jQuery of all time. One of the training videos I saw on Lynda.com said to add an anonymous variable around the files content. I tried a little bit of that too, but no luck.

[Here are my project files](https://github.com/meylo/Meylo-Responsive) (GitHub)

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting?

Comment: What kind of error you are getting? During the Gulp's process of combine/concat/compress? Or these tasks run successfully, but you get script error(s) when access the application throught the browser?

Comment: This is far too broad for Stack Overflow. This website also doesn't host questions which require links to external resources to be answerable. Requiring us to open your Github repo makes this question *extremely* off-topic.

Comment: Sorry it's the best I can do, since I'm learning.

Comment: One error is:
 `Uncaught ReferenceError:
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined VM8033:1
(anonymous function) VM8033:1
types script.js:13
jquery script.js:29
s script.js:1
e script.js:1
(anonymous function) script.js:1` @CaseyFalk @ChrisBenseler

Comment: Are you concatenating the jquery.js file? Didn't see it at https://github.com/meylo/Meylo-Responsive/blob/master/gulpfile.js and you are not including it in the index.html file

Comment: If you're having problems with your code; you need to put the steps into your question; as well as the smallest reproducible example of your problem. Simply linking to your project files and say 'take a look at this', is unacceptable and makes the question out of bounds for Stack Overflow. Not to mention, you aren't even telling us what those 'several errors' are.

Comment: Remove one file at a time from your list of files to concatenate. That will point you to the one that is causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have jQuery itself in your javascripts directory, or your jsSources in gulpfile.js.  If you're not including it on your site, before loading the output of the gulpfile, you'll get the errors you're seeing.

Just add jQuery to jsSources (probably first in the list?) and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm adding jQuery in my package.json as a node module. Do it still need it  called in my gulpfile.js

Comment: I removed all the js files compiled and just add one called test.js with nothing but a comment in it. I got this... `(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
//test 123
},{}]},{},[1])`